# Need to archive received emails

Tags: postfix-mta, spamassassin

I have a mail receiving setup where in Postfix (2.6.6) is the MTA and then I have amavisd-new (with spamassassin and CLamAV) as content filter.

I have enabled spam report header in my amavisd-new conf file.

I want to archive the files on local storage in maildir format. Is it possible via amavisd-new conf file?

In effect I want my archives to be created in following format or similar to one for each email received:

```
<BaseArchiveDirectory>/<UserEmailID>/<subjectOfEmail>.eml
```

Thanks

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following setting in my amavisd-new conf file:

```
$archive_quarantine_method = 'smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10050';
$archive_quarantine_to = 'archive-quarantine';
@archive_quarantine_to_maps = (\$archive_quarantine_to);
$mailfrom_to_quarantine = undef;  # undef keeps original sender
```

via above settings I could redirect a duplicate email stream to my archiving process (that I coded myself) listening on port 10050.

Above settings don't interfere in the basic path of the email content filter flows.